# What is the best way to have an entry for top-level categories?

Tags: categories, entry

I'm currently working on an eCommerce project with categories for products:

```
- Category 1
    - Sub-category 1
    - Sub-category 2
    - Sub-category 3
- Category 2
    - Sub-category 1
    - Sub-category 2
    - Sub-category 3
```

What I am hoping to achieve, is to give each top-level category its own entry in Craft, so I can apply my site-wide SEO, matrix content and utility fields.

I am aware you can apply fields to categories, but the whole double-clicking on a category and managing the content from the small modal window approach isn't ideal, especially with category pages that are a bit heavy on the content side.

These categories do have their own URL, and creating an entry with the same slug results in incrementation: `example-category-1`, which is to be expected.

Is there any way in Craft I can get round this? I guess if there is no other way I can apply fields to the category, but I wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little more consideration, I decided it was best instead not to use categories for this.

I have instead created a 'Product Categories' structure, and the relationships are handled through an entry field.

Comment: I was just going to recommend this. The big question generally comes down to whether products will ever have more than one parent. If not, then a structure is usually the way to go for all the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald That's exactly it, took me a while to get there though! And no, products will only have one 'Category' for this project, so on reflection a structure seems to be the way to go.

Comment: And if this ever changed, you can also later use categories to superimpose a separate category hierarchy on top of your already structured products. The structure can then just represent the default or canonical product structure.